# Puppeteer, как найти кнопку?

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

Как с помощью Puppeteer найти кнопку на странице instagram(вход). У нее нет никаких отличительных особенностей кроме того что в ней div, в котором текст "Войти". Как это сделать?

Comment: там используется такая штука как css modules, т.е. при каждой перезагрузке страницы генерируется новый класс из набора букв.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно использовать XPath и искать по тексту:

```js
const [button] = await page.$x('//button[div[text()="Log In"]]');
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, очень помогли.